# STL function in R: is it possible to make it backward looking?

Tags: r, time-series, smoothing, loess

I would like to smooth modeling input time series data using the [`stl` function in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/stl.html).

Based on my understanding, the function performs a local regression using data both forwards and backwards of each data point. I would not like to have data points include future information after the smoothing.

Is there a way to do that using R's stl function, short of looping the smoothing algorithm through gradually expanding time windows?

[Here is the function's paper](https://www.wessa.net/download/stl.pdf) by Cleveland et. al. for your reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in R (or in any other software). After all, the L stands for "loess", which is a local smoothing method. Every implementation of loess I have seen uses values on either side of the focal value. (loess is not limited to time series.)

You could look at Single Exponential Smoothing, which is implemented as `ses` in the `forecast` package. Or an equivalent state space formulation via `forecast::ets` or `smooth::es`.

Comment: Every implementation of Loess you have ever seen undoubtedly incorporated some procedure for dealing with the data at the extremes, which shows it *can* do one-sided smoothing.  You're likely still correct that it will be difficult to find software that has this option for smoothing all values.